# How to avoid Bokeh/Holoviews Import Errors (None of the backends could be imported)?

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews

Trying to get holoviews/bokeh working but unfortunately I am running into issues from the get go. Following the tutorial here: http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/Chord.html

But I'm getting stuck right at the beginning.

```
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts, dim
from bokeh.sampledata.les_mis import data

#all above imports run fine, I have ensured that bokeh and holoviews are
#updated (via pip install --upgrade xxx)



#following line produces the error:
hv.extension('bokeh')
```

The message I get is: ImportError: None of the backends could be imported

If it helps, when I tried troubleshooting this issue, I was told to try a different import:

```
import holoviews.plotting.bokeh
```

But this produces a different error: ImportError: cannot import name 'FreehandDrawTool'

As a result, I cannot even begin exploring the different visualization options bokeh offers.

I tried using both jupyter notebooks and atom. I have all dependencies installed and up-to-date as well (matplotlib, pandas, etc.) Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like you have an old version of bokeh. HoloViews requires at least Bokeh 1.0 and works best with Bokeh >=1.1.

Comment: You are right. I thought I had it all installed, but apparently not; rookie mistake! For anyone reading this in the future, simple fix for me was to run this line in the cmd: pip install holoviews[all]